# What is the difference between .NET micro framework and .NET compact framework?

Tags: .net, .net-micro-framework

What is the difference between .NET micro framework and .NET compact framework?

Can we run .NET micro framework / .NET compact framework applications on symbians based mobile phone?

On the internet I found 'Red Five Labs .Net for symbian' but it seems that the product was discontinued

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micro Framework is running directly on the hardware and can be seen like a kind of operating system.

Compact Framework is the runtime Envirenment for .NET on Windows CE and though needs an underlying OS to run.